# What prompted Du Bois to change "Jew" to "Immigrant" in "Of the Black Belt"?

Tags: the-souls-of-black-folk, w-e-b-du-bois

In my copy of *The Souls of Black Folk*, the essay "Of the Black Belt" references Jews as the inheritors of much property and land in the deep South.

A footnote in the book, however, reads:

> In later editions of *The Souls of Black Folk*, Du Bois changes all references to "Jews" to "immigrants."

Why? What prompted him to make that change?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Souls_of_Black_Folk#Textual_changes